# Resharper missing some unit tests

Tags: resharper

I have added a few more unit tests to my solution and these unit tests are not available to be executed in Resharper. They are also not listed in the Resharper Unit Test Explorer.

I can execute them via the Visual Studio Unit Test Explorer.

The same thing happens in the context menu of the test files. I get an entry to execute them via Visual Studio but not via Resharper.

My older test are all executable in Resharper and also listed in the explorer.

The tests are green.

Does anyone know how to get these test recognized by resharper?

Comment: Did you try a full rebuild, clearing R# caches and deleting the `bin`/`obj` folders?

Comment: when cleaning and rebuilding, the tests get the context-menu-entry for a short while. But by the time the build is through everything is back to like it was before.